# Does CVXPY use successive approximation for log_sum_exp?

Tags: cvxpy

I am solving an optimization problem with log_sum_exp as the objective function. I solved it using CVX in Matlab. However, the process was slow compared to other optimization problems. I am not sure if it is because of the successive approximation method used for the log_sum_exp function?

It seems that successive approximation is not mentioned in CVXPY. I am guessing that CVXPY does not use successive approximation? If successive approximation slows down the optimization, can I expedite the optimization by using CVXPY?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, CVXPY does not use successive approximation because the default solver ECOS supports the exponential cone directly, which can model log_sum_exp.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!